# Why is this code entering into an infinite loop

Tags: reactjs, spring, http

I have a React app and its meant to be a choose your own adventure thing, so it prints a message and then the user clicks a button making a decision which then determines what the next message will be.

Some of the messages don't have decisions associated and a new message should just print out automatically.  With my current set up it is working fine with when the user has to click a button to bring up the next message but when it is supposed to come up automatically it actually is displaying the next message repeatedly until it crashes.

I have tried a number of things all give the same result, the message that is supposed to show up only once shows up many times until the app crashes.

As a note the way the decisions work is that a list of integers (each one representing what the next child is) is sent to the server and then that list is used to traverse a tree -- like I said this is working fine when the player chooses a button which then adds an integer to the list depending on which button they choose.

When there are no buttons, I've tried to set up a method that simply automatically adds a `0` to the list (because if there is no choice it only has one child, the 0th child).

Here is my code, the `onDecide` method is used when there is a button and the `onNonDecide` method is used when there is not - I have tried just using the `onDecide` method originally and tried separating things to see if that worked but same issue.

Also note the `generateDecisions` method as that has an `if` statement which changes behavior when there are no decisions to be made.

```
class Home extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      previouslyPlayed: [],
      currentNode: {
        id: 1,
        text: 'Ah-- what the hell? Stupid thing.',
        decisions: [
          {
            id: 'n1d1',
            text: 'Who is this?',
            whichChild: 0,
            attitude: 0
          },
          {
            id: 'n1d2',
            text: 'What the hell yourself.',
            whichChild: 0,
            attitude: 0
          }
        ],
        speaker: 0,
        checkpoint: true
      },
      decisionList: [0]
    };

    this.onDecide = this.onDecide.bind(this);
    this.onNonDecide = this.onNonDecide.bind(this);

  }

  // Generate the previous messages to be displayed on the screen
  generateMessages() {
    let currentPrevious = this.state.previouslyPlayed;
    if (currentPrevious.indexOf(this.state.currentNode.text) < 0) {
      currentPrevious.push(this.state.currentNode.text);
    }

    return currentPrevious.map((text) =>
      <Message key={currentPrevious.indexOf(text)} text={text}/>
    );
  }

  // Generate the current decision that the play must make
  generateDecision() {
    if (this.state.currentNode.decisions.length <= 0) {
      let ignore = this.onNonDecide();
    } else {
      return <Decision decisions={this.state.currentNode.decisions} onDecide={this.onDecide}/>;
    }
  }

  updatePreviouslyPlayed(text) {
    let previouslyPlayed = this.state.previouslyPlayed;
    previouslyPlayed.push(text);
    this.setState({previouslyPlayed: previouslyPlayed});
  }

  updateDecisionList(whichChild) {
    let decisionList = this.state.decisionList;
    decisionList.push(whichChild);
    this.setState({decisionList: decisionList});
  }

  async onDecide(answer) {
    //Update the state to reflect the decision made
    this.updatePreviouslyPlayed(answer.text);
    this.updateDecisionList(answer.whichChild);

    let body = { decisionList: this.state.decisionList };

    let currentNode = await (await fetch('http://localhost:8080/decide', {
      method: 'POST',
      mode: 'cors',
      headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Cache-Control': 'no-cache',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(body),
    })).json();
    this.setState({currentNode: currentNode});
  }

  async onNonDecide() {
    this.updateDecisionList(0);

    let body = { decisionList: this.state.decisionList }

    let currentNode = await (await fetch('http://localhost:8080/decide', {
      method: 'POST',
      mode: 'cors',
      headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Cache-Control': 'no-cache',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(body),
    })).json();
    this.setState({currentNode: currentNode});
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Container id={'Application'}>
          {this.generateMessages()}
          {this.generateDecision()}
        </Container>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Home;
```

What I want this to do is set the `currentNode` one single time and that would then call the `generateMessages` and `generateDecisions` then printing out a new `Message` and possible a new `Decision`. What it does is start printing out the same `Message` hundreds of times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you have side effects that are changing state that are invoked in your `render` method.

> The render() function should be pure, meaning that it does not modify component state, it returns the same result each time it’s invoked, and it does not directly interact with the browser. - [React Docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#render)

For example, this path `render() -> this.generateDecision() -> this.onNonDecide() -> this.setState() -> render()` *(and repeat, possibly an infinite loop, I didn't consider all possible paths, just one example)*.

Another problem you'll like run into with re-renders not happening or other unexpected behavior is with mutating state like you have in `generateMessages`. The `previouslyPlayed` array is getting mutated with `currentPrevious.push`.

Comment: I see what you mean. Why is it that when the user is clicking a button that calls the `onDecide()` method, the same thing is not happening since `onDecide` also sets the state?